# Анимация линий и прямоугольников на Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Есть рамка нарисованная в ручную на Canvas.
Возможно ли сделать плавную анимацию отрисовки нескольких линий и прямоугольников сразу. Например как [сдесь](https://hsto.org/getpro/habr/post_images/fbe/302/7fd/fbe3027fdb6eb26c2d36c41ce1856b5c.gif) ?

```js
        var example = document.getElementById("border_canvas"),
            ctx     = example.getContext('2d'),
            h       = example.height ,
            w       = example.width ;

        ctx.strokeStyle = "#fcb040";
        ctx.lineWidth = '1';
        //общая рамка 
        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, w ,h);
        //внутриняя  рамка
        ctx.strokeRect(10, 10, w-20 ,h-20);
        //маленькие прямоугольники
        ctx.strokeRect(0,0,10,10);
        ctx.rect(w,0,10,10);
        ctx.rect(w-10,0,10,10);
        ctx.rect(0,h-10,10,10);
        ctx.rect(w-10,h-10,10,10);
        ctx.stroke();

        //статичние линии
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
        ctx.lineWidth = '2';
        ctx.moveTo(0,30);
        ctx.lineTo(0,50);
        ctx.moveTo(30,0);
        ctx.lineTo(50,0);

        ctx.moveTo(0,h-30);
        ctx.lineTo(0,h-50);

        ctx.moveTo(w-30,0);
        ctx.lineTo(w-50,0);

        ctx.moveTo(w,30);
        ctx.lineTo(w,50);
        ctx.moveTo(30,h);
        ctx.lineTo(50,h);

        ctx.moveTo(w,h-30);
        ctx.lineTo(w,h-50);
        ctx.moveTo(w-30,h);
        ctx.lineTo(w-50,h);

        ctx.stroke();
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas height='400' width='260' id='border_canvas' ></canvas>
```

Comment: через `requestAnimationFrame` задаешь анимацию, в которой рисуешь все эти линии с определенным шагом, а не сразу во всю длину. собcтвенно и всё

Comment: Если не трудно можете показать как сначала плавно отрисовать внутреннюю и общую рамку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом укуренный код выглядит так:

```js
var fps = 30;
var now;
var then = Date.now();
var interval = 1000 / fps;
var delta;
var example = document.getElementById("border_canvas"),
  ctx = example.getContext('2d'),
  h = example.height,
  w = example.width;
var shortLines = 0;
var lineSizeX, shortLines = 0;
var maxLineSizeX = 50,   maxShortLineSize = 30;
var innerLineX = 0,   maxInnerLineX = w,   deltaPathBorder = 2.3;
var innerLineY = 0,   maxInnerLineY = h;
var outerLineX = 0,   maxOuterLineX = w;
var outerLineY = 0,   maxOuterLineY = h;
var deltaPath = 1.1;

function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  now = Date.now();
  delta = now - then;

  if (delta > interval) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#fcb040";
    ctx.lineWidth = '1';

    if (innerLineX <= maxInnerLineX)
      innerLineX += deltaPathBorder;
    if (innerLineY <= maxInnerLineY)
      innerLineY += deltaPathBorder;
    if (outerLineX <= maxOuterLineX)
      outerLineX += deltaPathBorder;
    if (outerLineY <= maxOuterLineY)
      outerLineY += deltaPathBorder;


    //общая рамка       
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(outerLineX, 0);
    ctx.moveTo(w, h);
    ctx.lineTo(w - outerLineX, h);

    ctx.moveTo(w, h);
    ctx.lineTo(w, h - outerLineY);
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, outerLineY);

    //внутриняя  рамка
    ctx.moveTo(0, 10);
    ctx.lineTo(innerLineX, 10);
    ctx.moveTo(w, h - 10);
    ctx.lineTo(w - innerLineX, h - 10);

    ctx.moveTo(w - 10, h - 10);
    ctx.lineTo(w - 10, h - innerLineY);
    ctx.moveTo(10, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(10, innerLineY);

    ctx.stroke();
    //статичние линии
    if (lineSizeX < maxLineSizeX)
      lineSizeX += deltaPath;
    if (shortLines < maxShortLineSize)
      shortLines += deltaPath;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.lineWidth = '2';
    ctx.moveTo(0, shortLines);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 50);
    ctx.moveTo(shortLines, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(50, 0);

    ctx.moveTo(0, h - 30);
    ctx.lineTo(0, h - 50);

    ctx.moveTo(w - shortLines, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(w - 50, 0);

    ctx.moveTo(w, shortLines);
    ctx.lineTo(w, 50);
    ctx.moveTo(shortLines, h);
    ctx.lineTo(50, h);

    ctx.moveTo(w, h - shortLines);
    ctx.lineTo(w, h - 50);
    ctx.moveTo(w - shortLines, h);
    ctx.lineTo(w - 50, h);

    ctx.stroke();

    then = now - (delta % interval);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  draw();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas height='400' width='260' id='border_canvas'></canvas>
```

Тут есть что улучшать.... ОЧЕНЬ МНОГО есть чего улучшать...но суть наверное должна быть понятна...

[requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) - указывает браузеру на то, что вы хотите произвести анимацию, и просит его запланировать перерисовку на следующем кадре анимации. В качестве параметра метод получает функцию, которая будет вызвана перед перерисовкой.

Ну а там уже внутри метода делайте что хотите: например плавно увеличивайте длину линии до определенных размеров или прыгать мячик от стен.

Очень настоятельно рекомендую прочитать про анимацию и `requestAnimationFrame` и попробовать самому всё доделать, а не просто скопипастить тупой (а он на данный момент таковым является) код из моего ответа ;-)

Comment: Спасибо вам,теперь понятно над чем работать

Comment: @JavAs да, обязательно почитай литературу на этот счет. и особенно про неодинаковость времени между кадрами, которую надо компенсировать в каждом фрейме.

Answer (score 1):

Для анимации canvas нужно несколько раз в секунду перерисовывать холст, все операции по перерисовке заключают в функцию, а через `setTimeout()`,`setInterval()` или `requestAnimationFrame` вызывают её несколько раз в секунду. Вариант реализации, через `requestAnimationFrame` ниже.

```js
var example = document.getElementById("border_canvas"),
            ctx     = example.getContext('2d'),
            h       = example.height ,
            w       = example.width ;
            
var squarePosition_x = 10;
var squarePosition_y = 10;
       
function render() {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#fcb040";
        ctx.lineWidth = '1';
        //общая рамка 
        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, w ,h);
        //внутриняя  рамка
        ctx.strokeRect(10, 10, 0.1 ,squarePosition_x);
        ctx.strokeRect(10, 10, squarePosition_y ,0.1);
        ctx.strokeRect(w-10, h-10, 0.1 ,-squarePosition_x);
        ctx.strokeRect(w-10, h-10,-squarePosition_y ,0.1);
        //маленькие прямоугольники
        ctx.strokeRect(0,0,10,10);
        ctx.rect(w,0,10,10);
        ctx.rect(w-10,0,10,10);
        ctx.rect(0,h-10,10,10);
        ctx.rect(w-10,h-10,10,10);
        ctx.stroke();
        //увеличение значений для анимации
        squarePosition_y +=1; 
        squarePosition_x +=1.7;
        //рекурсия для бекончной перерисовки
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
        
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas height='400' width='260' id='border_canvas' ></canvas>
```